# How to create a vanity url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, vanity-url

I would like to know how to create a vanity url for a website.

Ideally I would like to be able to put this on a flyer:

www.charity.org.uk/monthlydonation

and when that is entered, it will go off to:

www.charity.org.uk/donate/monthly-donation.php

I've been reading about vanity urls, redirects and rewrites but quite frankly I'm not even sure what I need to do this?

I tried the following in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RedirectMatch 301 /monthlydonation /donate/monthly-donation.php
```

but got an error message saying there was a redirect loop.

All time and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using mod_rewrite instead, `RedirectMatch` is part of mod_alias and processes the request separate from mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^monthlydonation$ /donate/monthly-donation.php [L]
```

Additionally, the reason why you're getting a redirect loop is that `RedirectMatch` expects a regex and not just a path. So `/monthlydonation` is the matching pattern, and that happens to also match the redirect's target: "/donate **/monthly-donation**.php".

Comment: Thanks very much for your help with this.  That works perfectly.  Can you recommend any sites which have good tutorials for this type of stuff?